# I have question about my Bmw 325I 1995

Tags: part-interchange, 318ti, 325i

Could you use parts from a bmw 325i 1995 on a bmw 318ti 1995

Comment: Welcome to the site. It really depends on which parts you are talking about. Some parts will interchange without issue since these are both 300 series Bimmers from the same year. Other parts, like for the engines, probably won't. It really depends on what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

This answer depends on the specific part. I used to have a '94 318is and from what I remember a lot of the parts were identical across the whole 3-series line. Your best bet is looking up the part number that you want to replace, and see if they match for both models.  I regularly purchased parts from Bavauto.com. You can look up parts by model on their site. Look it up for both models and see if the part numbers match.